# Split a file using awk based on modulus of first column of input file

Tags: shell, awk

I have an input file with following dataset -

```
1234567,1234444,34567
2345678,9878979,54354
1222222,8763481,89374
3444444,8978979,78346
```

I want to split this file based on the modulus (10) of first column defined in the input file. So I want to group all the data that belongs to set (which matches the mod) and put it in new file.
So for this input data,
i want to have four different files. and the output name must be something like -

```
File 1 - output2.txt
1222222,8763481,89374
File 2 - output4.txt
3444444,8978979,78346
```

and so on.

Could you help me provide an awk statement that perform this?

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can use the `%` modulus operator:

```
$ awk '{print > $1%10}' file
```

You can also add some text in the file name:

```
$ awk '{print > "output"$1%10".txt"}' file
```

---

In my case it generates:

```
$ls
output2.txt  output4.txt  output7.txt  output8.txt
```

And for example `file2` is as follows:

```
$ cat output2.txt
1222222,8763481,89374
```

Answer (score 0):

grep will do

```
grep '^[0-9]*2,' your_file > output2.txt
grep '^[0-9]*4,' your_file > output4.txt
```

awk version

```
awk '/^[0-9]*2,/' your_file > output2.txt
```